# Creating NSG using Azure python sdk does not use the security rule

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-sdk-python

I am using

`λ pip show azure
Name: azure
Version: 2.0.0`

I want to create a NSG with a specific security rule. I have the following code.

```

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
subscription_id = 'my-id'
credentials = ...

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Compute')
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Network')

resource_group_name = 'test-rg'

security_rule = SecurityRule( protocol='Tcp', source_address_prefix='Internet', 
                              source_port_range="*", destination_port_range="3389", priority=100,
                              destination_address_prefix='*', access='Allow', direction='Inbound')
nsg_params = NetworkSecurityGroup(id='test-nsg', location='UK South', tags={ 'name' : 'testnsg' })
network_client.network_security_groups.create_or_update(resource_group_name, "test-nsg", parameters=nsg_params, security_rules=[security_rule])
```

This does create the NSG fine but fails to create the proper rules.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use this script to achieve it:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient

subscription_id = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx',
    secret = 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx',
    tenant = 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx'
)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Compute')
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Network')

resource_group_name = 'test-rg'


parameters = NetworkSecurityGroup()
parameters.location = 'UK South'

parameters.security_rules = [SecurityRule('Tcp', '*', '*', 'Allow', 'Inbound', description='Allow RDP port 3389',
                                 source_port_range='*', destination_port_range='3389', priority=100, name='RDP01')]   


network_client.network_security_groups.create_or_update(resource_group_name, "test-nsg", parameters)
```

`network_client.network_security_groups.create_or_update` only have **three** values, **resource_group**, **security_group_name** and **parametes**.

More information about `network_client.network_security_groups.create_or_update`, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/lmazuel/azurerm/blob/master/azure_rm_common.py).