# How to create Azure Network Security Group via Python SDK

Tags: python, azure

I'm using Azure Python SDK to deploy Azure VM. I can create VM with Network Security Group without any issue via the Azure portal. However, I failed to create a Network Security Group by using API like:

```
async_nsg_create=network_client.network_security_groups.begin_create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    NSG_NAME,
    nsg_parameters
)
```

It always complains that I "does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/write'".
However, I can create a Network Security Group via the Azure portal by clicking "create a resource" or add new source in Resource Group. I suspect I may have to create NSG via ResourceManagementClient, but I couldn't find any useful info in API doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resourcemanagementclient?view=azure-python#models-api-version--2020-06-01--

I checked the solution in this issue: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941544/creating-nsg-using-azure-python-sdk-does-not-use-the-security-rule), but failed at step: `resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Compute')` and it complains:"does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/register/action'"

Comment: What credentials are being used by the scrip/code? Check [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-virtual-machines?tabs=cmd#3-write-code-to-provision-a-virtual-machine) for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means your client does not have the permission to do the operations, you need to add it as an RBAC role in your resource group/subscription.

> However, I can create a Network Security Group via the Azure portal by clicking "create a resource" or add new source in Resource Group.

In the portal, your are using the account logged in the portal, if you are using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941544/creating-nsg-using-azure-python-sdk-does-not-use-the-security-rule), it uses the credentials of the service principal, it is different.

---

Here is a complete sample works for me, you follow the steps below.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

2.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

3.Navigate to the resource group or the subscription -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> add service principal of the AD App as an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor`, details follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

4.Then use the code below.

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models import SecurityRule

tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"
client_id = "<client-id>"
client_secret = "<client-secret>"
subscription_id = "<subscription-id>"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

resource_group_name = "<group-name>"
nsg_name = "testnsg"

nsg_params = NetworkSecurityGroup(id= "testnsg", location="UK South", tags={ "name" : "testnsg" })
nsg = network_client.network_security_groups.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name, "testnsg", parameters=nsg_params)
print(nsg.result().as_dict())
```

[image]

5.Check in the portal:

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to use the user account, you just need to use `AzureCliCredential`.

1.Install the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli), then login your account with `az login` in a local terminal, e.g. powershell.

2.After login, change the code like below and run it.

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models import SecurityRule


subscription_id = "<subscription-id>"

credential = AzureCliCredential()
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

resource_group_name = "<group-name>"
nsg_name = "testnsg"

nsg_params = NetworkSecurityGroup(id= "testnsg", location="UK South", tags={ "name" : "testnsg" })
nsg = network_client.network_security_groups.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name, "testnsg", parameters=nsg_params)
print(nsg.result().as_dict())
```

Comment: Thank you for concrete response. I think my current issue is at step: "subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add -> add service principal of the AD App as an RBAC", I can't assign permission to the app I created. I will reach out my admin tomorrow.

Comment: coming back to this question again. I can't get my service principal to have additional access. I was told to use my login account. Do you whether there is any way to invoke API by using a login account credential?