# Azure Pyhton Sdk :: 1. Create Azure VNET 2. enable Flow log on NET 3. Attach VNET to Azure Virtual WAN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-python-sdk

I want to create Azure VNET programmatically with Azure python SDK then enable the NSG flow logs on NET and finally attach the VNET to the Azure virtual WAN.

Answer (score 0):

**Install the management package with pip.**([Reference-MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/network?view=azure-python))

Bash

> pip install azure-mgmt-network

**Create a virtual network and an associated subnet.**

Python

```
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

GROUP_NAME = 'resource-group'
VNET_NAME = 'your-vnet-identifier'
LOCATION = 'region'
SUBNET_NAME = 'your-subnet-identifier'

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, 'your-subscription-id')

async_vnet_creation = network_client.virtual_networks.create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    VNET_NAME,
    {
        'location': LOCATION,
        'address_space': {
            'address_prefixes': ['10.0.0.0/16']
        }
    }
)
async_vnet_creation.wait()

# Create Subnet
async_subnet_creation = network_client.subnets.create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    VNET_NAME,
    SUBNET_NAME,
    {'address_prefix': '10.0.0.0/24'}
)
subnet_info = async_subnet_creation.result()
```

**Create a NSG with a specific security rule.**
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941544/creating-nsg-using-azure-python-sdk-does-not-use-the-security-rule)

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import NetworkSecurityGroup
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_03_01.models import SecurityRule
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient

subscription_id = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx',
    secret = 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx',
    tenant = 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxx'
)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Compute')
resource_client.providers.register('Microsoft.Network')

resource_group_name = 'test-rg'
nsg_name = "testnsg"
parameters = NetworkSecurityGroup(id= "testnsg", location="UK South", tags={ "name" : "testnsg" })


parameters.security_rules = [SecurityRule('Tcp', '*', '*', 'Allow', 'Inbound', description='Allow RDP port 3389',source_port_range='*', destination_port_range='3389', priority=100, name='RDP01')]   


network_client.network_security_groups.create_or_update(resource_group_name, "test-nsg", parameters)

print(“completed  creating security rules”)
```

**Or** you can

**Associate the NSG to an existing subnet,  using python sdk**
[SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189108/how-to-create-azure-network-security-group-via-python-sdk)

```
subscription_id = "xxxxxx"
credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
  client_id="xxxxx",
  secret="xxxxx",
  tenant="xxxxx"
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

resource_group_name = "xxxxx"
vnet_name = "xxxxx"
subnet_name = "xxxxx"
sunet_data = {
  "properties": {
    "addressSpace": {
      "addressPrefixes": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    "subnets": [
      {
        "name": "default",
        "properties": {
          "addressPrefix": "*",
          "networkSecurityGroup": {
            "id": networkSecurityGroupId ,
            "location": "eastasia"
            }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "location": "eastasia"
}

result = network_client.subnets.create_or_update(resource_group_name, vnet_name, subnet_name, subnet_data)
```

> Note: Source/destination_port_ranges simply accepts a list of accepted
> ports or port ranges.  For example: ['80', '100-200'] or other
> example: destination_port_range=[1000,2000] However, * can only be
> used with the standalone property and not in the list.
> source/destination_address_prefixes accepts a list of CIDR addresses,
> ex: ['10.0.0.0/24', '11.0.0.0/24'].  To use * or a tag (Internet or
> VirtualNetwork for example) you must use the singular property. They
> cannot be used in the list.

You can check out this document  > [Operations module](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-network/10.0.0/azure.mgmt.network.v2019_02_01.operations.html#azure.mgmt.network.v2019_02_01.operations.VirtualWansOperations)   where various operations are listed in python sdk. You can click on [[source]](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-network/10.0.0/_modules/azure/mgmt/network/v2019_02_01/operations/_virtual_wans_operations.html#VirtualWansOperations.create_or_update)  of the required operation to get the code to be used:
Example:
[image]

Similar to nsg and vnet ,set required  wan parameters  and use:

```
create_or_update(resource_group_name, virtual_wan_name, wan_parameters, custom_headers=None, raw=False, polling=True, **operation_config)
```

Also see virtual network operations and add vpn gateway if required
[Sample for Creating Virtual Network Gateway](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/910)

If you want use azure portal see >  [Connect a virtual network gateway to an Azure Virtual WAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/connect-virtual-network-gateway-vwan#:%7E:text=Connect%20a%20VPN%20Gateway%20%28virtual%20network%20gateway%29%20to,network%20gateways.%205%205.%20Create%20connections.%20More%20items)